# Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 8192 (not at position 0)

Tags: java, json, jar

I am working on this project where I get Json responses and turn them in to objects of type shop. A requirement is to make a jar file of the project and insert it in to another project that will create a File out of those objects. So far so good. The problems start here:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {
       /* Propertiess practise = new Propertiess();
        practise.InitializeConfigParameters();
        practise.Print();*/
        ArrayList<Shop> ArrayofShops = new ArrayList<>
(YelpJsonApi.SearchForShops("Burgers", "San Francisco"));

 }
```

When I run main from the first project eveything runs perfect, but when I run the same main from my second project this error occures:

```
Exception in thread "main" Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 8192.
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at Basics.YelpJsonApi.SearchForShops(YelpJsonApi.java:53)
at Storage.Demo.main(Demo.java:21)
```

Java Result: 1

This error points to this part:

```
       public class YelpJsonApi {
private static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
private static final File shops = new File("C:\\Users\\Stathis\\Documents\\shops.txt");

public static ArrayList<Shop> SearchForShops(String CityName, String Category) throws IOException, Exception{
    String url = "someLink" + Category + "&location=" + CityName;

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
            .header("Authorization", "someText")
            .ignoreContentType(true)
            .get();

    String responseText = doc.text();
    //System.out.println("TEXT:" + responseText);
    System.out.println("**************************************************");

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    File shops = new File("shops.txt");
    ArrayList<Shop> shopListFromApi = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
       // Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(shops));
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(shops);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(responseText);



        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(shops));
        StringReader rT = new StringReader(responseText); // διαφορετικά η από κάτω γραμμή θα πετάει error String cannot be converted to reader 
        jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(rT);
        ...
}
```

even though I have read most articles at stackoverflow (and other sites) and also have tried most options the error won't seem to get away. I have a suspicion that there might be some problem with my file (even though I have tried storing my info to other files) since the EOF exception is at position 8192 and not at the begining.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I assume `YelpJsonApi.SearchForShops` is **your** library? Then A) post a [mcve] with that because the bug is in that method! and B) read about java naming conventions. Your should name your package differently, and method names go lowerCase() for example.

Comment: It seems like there is a problem with your input file (shops.txt). Could you post it here? Maybe it is missing a closing parenthesis or sth.

Comment: Ok, I have edited the code part to be more precise!

Comment: Turns Out that when I put :
 Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(shops));
inside comments the problem got fixed!